# Click to change range value becomes less responsive on react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Not sure if I did something wrong, but when I add onMouseDown with useEffect, the click to change range value becomes less responsive.

Here's some code:

```
function Slider() {
  const min = 1;
  const max = 100;
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [dragStarted, setDragStarted] = React.useState(false);
  const [dragging, setDragging] = React.useState(false);
  const percentage = (value - min) / (max - min);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (dragStarted && !dragging) {
      console.log('dragging');
      setDragging(true);
    }
  }, [percentage, dragStarted]);


    return (
    <input
      value={value}
      min={min}
      max={max}
      step="1"
      onChange={({ target }) => setValue(target.value)}
      onMouseDown={(e) => {
        setDragStarted(true);
      }}
      onMouseUp={(e) => {
        setDragStarted(false);
        setDragging(false);
      }}
      type="range" 
    ></input>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Slider />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/btcpdugz/25/

Expected result: Should work normally when clicking on the range.
Actual result: Sometimes thumb doesn't move or value doesn't change when clicking on the range.

Comment: I noticed when I remove dragStarted in useEffect it becomes more responsive again... but then React complains "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dragStarted'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the logging useEffect

```
function TodoApp() {
  const min = 1;
  const max = 100;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [dragStarted, setDragStarted] = React.useState(false);
  const [dragging, setDragging] = React.useState(false);      

  React.useEffect(() => {
     console.log(dragStarted, dragging);
  }, [dragStarted, dragging]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (dragStarted && !dragging) {
      setDragging(true);
    }
  }, [value]);


    return (
    <input
      value={value}
      min={min}
      max={max}
      step="1"
      onChange={({ target }) => setValue(target.value)}
      onMouseDown={(e) => {
        setDragStarted(true);
      }}
      onMouseUp={(e) => {
        setDragStarted(false);
        setDragging(false);
      }}
      type="range" 
    ></input>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```